# kotlin group by sum of property value in an arraylist

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an arraylist that contains list of objects like below:

```
[Activities(id=3116, studentID=5c1a7986c98da061141475b4, actionID=1234, actionName=hohoho, totalPoints=100),
Activities(id=3117, studentID=5c1a7986c98da061141475b4, actionID=4321, actionName=lalala, totalPoints=7),
Activities(id=3118, studentID=5c1a7986c98da061141475b4, actionID=4321, actionName=lalala, totalPoints=4),
Activities(id=3119, studentID=5c1a7986c98da061141475b4, actionID=1234, actionName=hohoho, totalPoints=10)]
```

Is there any kotlin functions that I can use that can sum the `totalPoints` based on group `actionID` from above? If the above arraylist is in sql instead, I can do something like `SELECT actionID, SUM(totalPoints) FROM activities GROUP BY actionID`, which will return

```
actionID     totalPoints
1234         110
4321         11
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the list of `activities`, then you can get the sum of  `totalPoints` grouping by `actionID` as below

```
val result = activities
        .groupBy { it.actionID }
        .mapValues { entry -> entry.value.sumBy { it.totalPoints } }
```

`result` would be a map containing the `actionID` as its key and value as the sum of `totalPoints` for the respective `actionID`

Printing `result` would give

```
{1234=110, 4321=11}
```

Comment: thanks, but is there anyway I can sort the result? maybe adding something like `.sortBy { it.actionID }`? Actually I tried doing this but it returns error haha

Comment: @imin adding a `.toSortedMap()` at the end would sort the result by keys, which would be `actionID` in this case

Answer (score 4):

```
val result = list.groupingBy { it.actionID }
        .fold(0) { acc, element -> acc + element.totalPoints }
```

`groupingBy` is kind of lazy `groupBy`, it doesn't create intermediate collection, therefore, it should be faster than `groupBy` when we need to do additional actions after grouping. After `groupingBy` we can use `fold` to sum elements from the same group.